# How to read comma separated variables and append them in string buffer in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm looking for option to read the variable which has comma separated fields (Eg: `a,b,c,d,e,f`)and generate an another variable from that (eg:`a,'a',b,'b',c,'c',d,'d',e,'e',f,'f'`). I have tried with 'FOR' loop approach but its adding comma at the end. 
Eg:

```
Var1=a,b,c,d,e,f
```

Expected output:

```
Var2=a,'a',b,'b',c,'c',d,'d',e,'e',f,'f'

for i in $(echo $Var1 | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
    Var2="$i"",'""$i""',"
fi
done
```

I'm getting `Var2=a,'a',b,'b',c,'c',d,'d',e,'e',f,'f',`  ending with comma
Is there any good approach to get it done without making more complex?

Thanks
DMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this in `sed`.

```
$ var1="a,b,c,d,e,f,"
$ var2=$(sed -e "s/[a-z]/&,\'&\'/g" -e 's/,$//g' <<<"$var1")
$ echo $var2
a,'a',b,'b',c,'c',d,'d',e,'e',f,'f'
```

The first `-e` in `sed` repeats the single characters and then the next `-e` removes the end comma `,`.

The above will *not* work if `var1` has multiple characters between each comma `,`. For that use, `-E` or `regex` option for `sed`

```
$ var1='abc,192,hk3,def,HoZ,'
$ var2=$(sed -E -e "s/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/&,\'&\'/g" -e 's/,$//g' <<<"$var1")
$ echo "$var2"
abc,'abc',192,'192',hk3,'hk3',def,'def',HoZ,'HoZ'
```

Comment: This works perfectly "var2=$(sed -E -e "s/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/&,\'&\'/g" -e 's/,$//g' <<<"$var1")" . I will vote this answer. Can you explain me the sed command in detail? What would be the significant of each characters in it?

Comment: How do I change In case if I want to change the order (first write value with single quotes and value alone) , say for eg: (Var2='abc',abc,'192',192,'hk3',hk3,'def',def,'HoZ',HoZ)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ? Change order for what ?

Comment: This is helping me to get in change the order - var2=$(sed -E -e "s/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/'&',&/g" -e 's/,$//g' <<<"$var1"). Adding quotes for first "&" and removing it from second one.  I got the below results,  'abc',abc,'192',192,'hk3',hk3,'def',def,'HoZ',HoZ

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to deal with an extra comma one way or another.

Here's what I'd offer as a solution. I'm also using an actual array to make sure we can process strings with spaces:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Input variable
VAR1=a,b,c,d,e,f

# Read VAR1 into an array
IFS=',' read -r -a VAR1_ARRAY <<< ${VAR1}

VAR2=''

for EL in ${VAR1_ARRAY[@]}; do
  VAR2="${VAR2},${EL},'${EL}'"
done

# Remove a leading comma
VAR2=${VAR2:1:${#VAR2} - 1}

echo ${VAR2}
```

The output:

```
a,'a',b,'b',c,'c',d,'d',e,'e',f,'f'
```

Comment: I'd suggest: 1) quoting expansions 2) not using upper-case variables 3) to add text to a variable: `var2+=something` 4) to remove the leading comma: `var2=${var2#,}`

Comment: Thanks for your time